# Sending client certificate with JMeter load test

Tags: http, https, jmeter, ssl-certificate, load-testing

I am attempting to use a certificate with JMeter and can see that it appears to be loaded fine from the logs.

```
INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: certificate.jks type jks
INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore
```

Yet, when I send the Http Request, the results from the server just keep stating 'Client Certificate Not Provided'.

Below are the parameters I've used on the command line.

```
-D javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks 
-D javax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificate.jks 
-D javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password123
```

All the examples I can find simply state that if I configure the Jmeter element 'KeyStore Configuration' with the alias, it should send the certificate with the requests.  It does not seem to be doing so.  For the record, I have also tried to use the p12 cert and set the type to pkcs12 with the same results.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact given you have only one certificate you don't need the Keystore Configuration at all, **just remove it from the test plan** and your setup should start working normally

---

Most probably your Keystore Configuration is not correct, for instance the "variable name holding certificate alias" is not set or doesn't match the record in the keystore

[image]

Check its value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and make sure that certificate with this alias exists in the keystore. You can see a working sample in [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) article

Comment: So as long as I list it in the startup -D switch, and it's selected I shouldn't need the Keystore Configuration?  Do I need to modify the request at all to send it then?

Comment: You don't need the Keystore Configuration if you have only one certificate